# Why is there a How in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

"Ramin Shokrizade is a game designer. *And he says he likes how kids are not being manipulated into clicking buttons to buy stuff within this game itself.* Lots of other popular games are designed to encourage in-game purchases. "

I have a question. In the following sentence, "And he says he likes how kids are not being manipulated into clicking buttons to buy stuff within this game itself.", I do not understand why there is "how" in the sentence.  Couldn't have the author just written "And he says he likes *that/ the fact that* kids are not being manipulated into clicking buttons to buy stuff within this game itself."? What is the difference?

Comment: *I really like **how** people ask questions here!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"HOW" explains the use of stressing the way the second part of the sentence functions.

He says

he likes

how kids are not being manipulated

into clicking buttons to buy stuff within this game itself.

The above can surely be written replacing "how" with *that/ the fact that* but the first one is just concise and better way to present the same. Writing "how" also explains that the author is curious of *how such things happen*.